# Excel 2016 VBA Runtime error 13

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote the code below to clear the cell in column D only if the value of the cell in in the corresponding row of column B changes to a value that is part of a specific list/range (B118:B124). If I change the cell in B to any value that is not part of that list, the cell in the corresponding row in D will not clear (that is what I want).

The code below works fine, except, if for example I want to delete 5 (adjacent) cells in column B at the same time, I get runtime error 13. Same is the case if I enter a new value in the first of the deleted/blank cells and then try to auto fill it down to the rest of deleted/blank cells. Basically, the code below seems to not work if I want to change multiple cells in B at the same time (autofill,...). If I only delete/change one cell (in B) at a time, it works just fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)  

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B118:B124"), Target) Then
        Range("D" & Target.Row).ClearContents
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: By the way, the row that is highlighted when the error message comes up is: "If Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Range("B118:B124"), Target) Then"

Comment: hi urdearboy, the only thing that's missing from the code above is: Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range). It's obviously the very first line of code. Everything else is shown above. Thanks

Comment: Any idea what might cause the runtime error when I try to change multiple cells in B at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The standard site style would be to update your question rather than have clarifying comments. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the issue is that `COUNTIF` is expecting a singular value, not a range containing values. Try this instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In Range(Target.Address)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B118:B124"), cell) Then
            Range("D" & cell.Row).ClearContents
        End If
    Next cell
End If

End Sub
```

EDIT: Updated answer with everyone's contributions:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In Target
        If Not Intersect(cell, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B118:B124"), cell) Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Range("D" & cell.Row).ClearContents
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: For a neat coding pattern you must set Application.EnableEvents=False before the ClearContents line and set it back to True and prevent calling the event handler an infinite loop (although this would not be the case)

Comment: You check the intersect with Col B, but then loop over the entire Target range: you should only process the cells in the Intersect range. BTW `Range(Target.Address)` is the same as `Target`

Comment: @TimWilliams If I strip away everything between `Private Sub` and `End Sub` and just do `Debug.Print Target`, it's printing the `Target.Value`, so I was under the impression I needed to grab the address.

Comment: If you look at the method parameter, `Target` is already a `Range` object, so there's no need to do any conversion to get a range from it.  `Debug.Print Target` will output the *default property* of Target, which happens to be its `Value`. `Debug.Print Target` will error on a multi-cell Range, because `Value` is an array and not a single value.

Comment: Thanks Guys. DisplayName, where would I set Application.EnableEvents back to true? Afrer clearcontents line? thanks

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the explanation - I did not know that.

Comment: @Jac I've updated the answer to work a little more consistently.

Comment: Thanks dwirony. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting a range, you must process each individually in this case. Loop the range in target and done.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    For Each cell In Target
        If Not Intersect(cell, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B118:B124"), cell) Then
                Range("D" & cell.Row).ClearContents
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo, thanks for response. I have a hundred cells that I need this code to apply to. Isn't there a simpler/shorter way to solve this problem? It would be a pretty long code. If there is another way, I'd greatly appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Also, I'm new to VBA. What do you mean by loop? does it refer to a quick way of correcting the code?

Comment: never mind. just copied your code. Works great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it worked. Sorry for not replying on time to your questions, I am at work. Edit: strongly recommended to read a bit about VBA For Loops, you will use them a lot once you know how to use them.